# How to solve android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 & properly display data from a database to a cardview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am trying to build a card view that displays a list of data from my SQLite database. I use `grocery_item` class to create the recycler view & take the data from `MyDataBaseHelper` & put the data into ArrayList. In the same class, I then create an object of `captionedImagesAdapter` to create the view holder for the card view and bind the data from the ArrayLists to the Card Views.

However, whenever I try to run the program I receive the exception `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0` & the card views are not displayed on the `item_grocery.xml` layout. The line of code that is causing the problem is `at com.myapps.myapplication.captionedImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(captionedImagesAdapter.java:44)` which is `Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable (holder.cardView.getContext(), images [position]);` &
`at com.myapps.myapplication.captionedImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(captionedImagesAdapter.java:14)` which is `public class captionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <captionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder>`.

I have tried solving the problem by check if the ArrayList had null references but everything is fine and from the research, I have done the exception is caused because the resource cannot be found from `holder.cardView.getContext()`. However, I am stuck on this issue I don't know if I am displaying data from a database to a Recycler view the right way.

Here is the code for my `grocery_item.java`activity:

```
package com.myapps.myapplication;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class grocery_item extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList <String> groceryName;
ArrayList <Integer> groceryImages;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_grocery);

    RecyclerView groceryRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grocery_recycler_view);

    groceryName = new ArrayList<String>();
    groceryImages = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    accessDataBase();

    cursor = db.query("ITEMS", new String[] {"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID"}, null, null, null, null, null);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                groceryName.add (cursor.getString (0));
                groceryImages.add (cursor.getInt (1));
            }

        } 

        if (i != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                groceryName.add (cursor.getString (0));
                groceryImages.add (cursor.getInt (1));
            } else {
                Log.d ("blue", "the next record in the cursor was not found for the images");
            }
        }

    }

    captionedImagesAdapter adapter = new captionedImagesAdapter (groceryName, groceryImages);

    groceryRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    groceryRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    groceryRecycler.setAdapter (adapter);
}

public void accessDataBase () {
    MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if (db != null) {
            Log.d ("db", "db is is accessed");
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for my `item_grocery.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grocery_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Here is code for my `card_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the code for my `captionedImagesAdapter.java`:

```
package com.myapps.myapplication;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

public class captionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <captionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private int [] images;
private String [] names;

public captionedImagesAdapter (ArrayList <String> captions, ArrayList <Integer> imageIds) {

    images = new int [11];
    names = new String [11];

    for (int i = 0; i <11; i++) {
        images [i] = imageIds.get (i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        names [i] = captions.get (i);
    }
}

public captionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder (cv);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable (holder.cardView.getContext(), images [position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable (drawable);
    holder.textView.setText (names [position]);
}

public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d ("captionSize", String.valueOf(names.length));
    return names.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;
    private CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView view) {
        super(view);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        cardView = view;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for my SQLiteHelper:

```
package com.myapps.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "starbuzz";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ITEMS (" + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "NAME TEXT, " + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, " + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER) ;");
    insertItems (db, "Faan", "Bangla Faan", R.drawable.faan);
    insertItems (db, "Milk", "Whole Milk", R.drawable.milk);
    insertItems (db, "Egg", "A tray of Eggs", R.drawable.egg);
    insertItems (db, "Toilet Tissue", "A bag of toilet tissue", R.drawable.toilet_tissue);
    insertItems (db, "Kitchen Tissue", "A bag of kitchen tissue", R.drawable.kitchen_tissue);
    insertItems (db, "Bread", "a bag of bread", R.drawable.bread);
    insertItems (db, "Potatoe", "a sack of potatoe", R.drawable.potatoe);
    insertItems (db, "Onion", "a sack of onions", R.drawable.onion);
    insertItems (db, "Flour", "a packet of flour", R.drawable.flour);
    insertItems (db, "Tomatoe", "a packet of tomatoe", R.drawable.tomatoe);
    insertItems (db, "Corriandor", "a bag of corriandor", R.drawable.corriandor);
}

public void insertItems (SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description, int image) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put ("NAME", name);
    contentValues.put ("DESCRIPTION", description);
    contentValues.put ("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", image);
    db.insert ("ITEMS", null, contentValues);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Here is the exception I receive when I run the code:

```
2020-07-30 11:00:09.754 28815-28815/com.myapps.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapps.myapplication, PID: 28815
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:246)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:905)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:845)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:687)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
    at com.myapps.myapplication.captionedImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(captionedImagesAdapter.java:44)
    at com.myapps.myapplication.captionedImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(captionedImagesAdapter.java:14)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7178)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7258)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6125)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6391)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6231)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6227)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:572)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3941)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:786)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3333)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2810)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1930)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7988)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1154)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:977)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:893)
    2020-07-30 11:00:09.754 28815-28815/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
    android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:1082)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: What is the value of images [position] ?

Comment: The value of images [position] is the image resources from my database, I have edited my post & added the database code. The image resources from the image ArrayList are moved to the images array so now that int array holds references to the image resources.

Comment: You can use **Glide** or **Picasso** to load the images. If the issue is caused at the Drawable loading line. If you are not likely to use that try to pass the context of the parent activity and load the data. It's like pass the context of host activity through constructor and initialize and use it. It may work

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error after upgrading the following dependencies. After reverting them back, it got resolved.

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
```